# How do I import posts into a SharePoint 2007 blog?

Tags: 2007, blog, import

I had a blog on our 2010 installation but have replaced it with a blog on our 2007 instance (because it's public).  I want to move some of the posts from the 2010 blog into the 2007 one but seem to be having trouble creating posts.  I thought I'd import using a datasheet view, but they're all read only.  Linked tables in Access are the same story.  Do I really have to spend all afternoon writing a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might consider is using Live Writer. You can connect it to both environments, recall the posts from the 2010 environment, then post them to the new environment.

Comment: That only kind-of works.  The trouble is that I've got a couple of hundred articles, and the images get broken when they move.